# Excel Table Column Reference by Referencing Second Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

That's a terrible title, I know.

---

I have two tables.  The first is **UseCases**, which has columns for all the roles identified that apply, then a 1 or 0 in the *Role* column to indicate whether that role uses that use case, so:

```
ID | Description   | Worker | Manager | Executive
1  | Do stuff      |   1    |    1    |     1
2  | Manage People |   0    |    1    |     1
3  | Collect Bonus |   0    |    0    |     1
```

The second, **Roles**, lists the roles:

```
Role        | Use Case Count
Worker      |
Manager     |
Executive   |
```

In the *Use Case Count* column of the **Roles** table, I'm trying to count the number of use cases for that particular role, so Worker gets 1, Manager 2, and Executive 3.  If I'm explicit with the reference, I can use `=SUM(UseCases[Worker])` in the cell and get the result I'm after.  But I can't use something like `=SUM(UseCases[@[Role]])`, which throws an error.  Similarly `=SUM(UseCases[A2])` doesn't work.

How do I solve this problem in a manner that's dynamic enough that adding role names or updating them doesn't break things?  I'm open to alternate solutions.

Comment: Is the UseCase table already built, or do you have options to change how the data appears before you get it? If it could be built with 4 columns (id, description, role, 1/0 flag) then you could build a pivot table and display like you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a Sumproduct formula. The formula in column I is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(UseCases[[Worker]:[Executive]]*(UseCases[[#Headers],[Worker]:[Executive]]=[@Role]))
```

[image]

When you add new roles to the UseCases table, just make sure to insert them BETWEEN Worker and Executive, not before or after. That way, the reference with the `:` operator will cover `all columns starting from Worker to Executive`.

[image]

Edit:

You can also define named ranges with the Name Manager and use the range names in the formula. When you add more role names, you just need to make sure that the range name refers to the correct range.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RoleData*(RoleHeadings=[@Role]))
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: This appears to have done the trick.  Can I replace 'UseCases[[Worker]:[Executive]]' with a **range** such that it looks more like 'UseCases[RoleList]'?  I ask because the last role in the list (where I have Executive in the example) is actually "Reconciliation Specialist - Accounts Payable and Receivable (FI-CA)".  I'm going to ask if we can rename it, but it's hard to say if they'll be willing.

Comment: Well, apparently not.  Just tried it.  If you have any ideas, I'll... well, I'll appreciate them. :)

Comment: No. The reference uses the `:` operator which defines a range of cells that starts with the reference before the `:` sign and extends to the cell after the `:` sign. It will include all cells in between. If you don't want to use that approach, you could set up named ranges with the Name Manager. You would need one named range for the column headings and another named range for the column contents. And when you add new columns, you need to ensure that your named ranges cover all the columns.

Comment: You can use any column heading name. This one works fine for me, too. `=SUMPRODUCT(UseCases[[Worker]:[Reconciliation Specialist - Accounts Payable and Receivable (FI-CA)]]*(UseCases[[#Headers],[Worker]:[Reconciliation Specialist - Accounts Payable and Receivable (FI-CA)]]=[@Role]))`

Comment: I've added some details to my answer to incorporate the named range approach.